# Lazy load function adds new Doctype

Tags: wordpress

I have an image heavy WordPress site.

I'd like to use a `lazyload` plugin to load the images.

The plugin requites a '`img`' element like this:

```
    <img data-original=“img/example.jpg” src=“img/grey.gif” width=“640” height=“480”>
```

The output from **WordPress** is:

```
    <img class="" alt="" src="img/example.jpg" width="440" height="664" />
```

I'm using this function to create the required '`img`' element:

```
    function add_lazyload($content) {
         $dom = new DOMDocument();
         @$dom->loadHTML($content);

         foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
             $oldsrc = $node->getAttribute('src');
             $node->setAttribute("data-original", $oldsrc );
             $newsrc = ''.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/placeholder.png';
             $node->setAttribute("src", $newsrc);
         }
         $newHtml = $dom->saveHtml();
         return $newHtml;
    }

    add_filter('the_content', 'add_lazyload');
```

This creates the '`img`' elements I need but it surrounds them in a new `Doctype`, `html` and `body` elements.

Is it possible to create the '`img`' elements without the new `Doctype`, `html` and `body`.

Comment: You are creating a new DOM Document instead of appending them to the current, so of course, it's doing what you've told it to.

Comment: I can see it's doing that, I got the code from another old forum post. How would I append the updated 'img' element to the current document

Comment: try `$dom = document`, see if that works although it may overwrite you're content, I didn't try it.